# Is an Ubuntu CD still available for mail delivery?

Tags: cd

Is it still possible to receive via mail a CD copy of Ubuntu to use

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can buy them at [Canonical Store](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17) or at [OSDisk](https://www.osdisc.com/products/ubuntu/v1404lts?affiliate=distrowatch). The free Shipit program has been [cancelled](http://www.ubuntu.com/shipit).